# C++ dynamic libraries - link symbols at runtime on OS X

Tags: c++, c, macos, dynamic-linking

I'm writing a plugin based emulation system. The way this works is that the main system sets up an ImGui instance and the plugins use ImGui to draw windows to the screen. I'm using a static build of ImGui which is embedded in the host program and linked to at run time; on Linux, this works fine, because the plugin .so files don't need to link against ImGui at compile time, only at run time. On OS X I get errors about "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" when trying to link the .dylibs.

Is there a way to tell OS X to leave the linking for run-time also?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer elsewhere - I need to add the `-undefined dynamic_lookup` flag on OS X.